# Are comparison flags cleared after a jump in assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86

A basic question but I have trouble finding an answer. In assembly, disregarding which one, are the flags used to perform `JE, JNE, JL, JG, JLE, JGE` usually all cleared after the jump is done ?

Comment: No, they are not. The jumps don't affect flags, and you don't normally clear them by hand either.

Comment: Understood, thank you!

Comment: The Intel Software Development Manual is clear about this, in the `Jcc` lemma it says "Flags Affected: None"

Comment: Why do you even ask? Manual says: "Flags Affected: None". Are you trying to use assembler without looking into a reference? It works only if you memorize commands.

Comment: @AlexGuteniev I am writing a basic virtual processor and needed to know what to do with my own FLAGS register after a jump. I wasn't aware of the manual.

Comment: Your own instructions? The question is a bit vague about the intent then

Comment: @Katoptriss If you are writing your own virtual processor and want it to confirm to the x86 architecture, you should definitely read these manuals.  If you are writing your own virtual processor with a custom architecture, you can do whatever you like.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Conditional jump instructions do not set flags.  So you can for example jump multiple times on the same comparison:

```
cmp eax, ecx
jl foo         ; if eax < ecx jump to foo
jg bar         ; if eax > ecx jump to bar
jmp baz        ; otherwise jump to baz
```

Comment: Although, if at all possible, you might want to try to have the code **fall through** into *baz* (so as to not waste a `jmp baz` instruction. `cmp eax, ecx` `jl foo` `jg bar` `baz:` `...`

Comment: @SepRoland Yes, this is usually the case.  I wanted to illustrate that no conditional jump for `baz` is needed.